# How do I perform background tasks while blocking the caller

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'd like to create a function that performs multiple background operations but the caller should not be aware of its asynchronous nature. So when a caller calls that function it should block the caller's thread and continue after it finishes all the tasks.
Ideally, the function should be called by just invoking its name (say `blockingFunction()`).
How do I achieve that?
(The main thread isn't a concern here)

Comment: It sounds like you have a request to make, but what is your question?

Comment: Well, I didn't say anything about the main thread. It should block any thread the caller invokes the function on. And why do you think the app would crash if you block the main thread? It would just freeze.

Comment: You use dispatch queue with sync so the function will call code in a queue but will wait until it is finished.  This other queue like main thread will not be impacted.

Comment: “And why do you think the app would crash if you block the main thread? It would just freeze.” … It will freeze, but if you block the main thread at the wrong time, the watchdog process, which checks for unresponsive apps, will unceremoniously kill your app. See watchdog discussion [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-the-cause-of-common-crashes/) or [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations/).

Comment: It’s a horrible pattern and I wouldn’t recommend it, but, strictly speaking, you can make an asynchronous method behave synchronously by calling `wait` on semaphore or dispatch group. It’s inefficient, temporarily ties up one of the very limited background worker threads, introduces potential deadlock risks, and, as discussed above, if done from main thread, results in horrible UX, with frozen UI, and can throw 0x8badf00d watchdog issues. Instead, I’d encourage you to embrace asynchronous patterns rather than fight them.

Answer (score 1):

We will posit the following test method:

```
func test() {
    print("start")
    self.doYourThing()
    print("finish")
}
```

That function is internally synchronous: it proceeds one line at a time from start to finish.

We also have an asynchronous method using an old-fashioned completion handler:

```
func behaveAsynchronously(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+10) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

We will consider the problem solved if `doYourThing` somehow calls `behaveAsynchronously` and yet "finish" prints 10 seconds after "start". Ready? Here we go:

```
func doYourThing() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    self.behaveAsynchronously {
        group.leave()
    }
    group.wait()
}
```

QED.

Note that we are blocking the main thread for 10 seconds, which is illegal; if you did that in real life, you'd crash. Also, there must be multiple threads in the story, or we would be attempting to `wait` on the same thread we are delayed on and a deadlock results.